# Haskell: check if string is valid number

Tags: validation, haskell

How do I check for a decimal point when checking a string is a valid number?

What I am thinking is that I use something like the following, but add code to check for the decimal point!

```
isNumber :: String -> Bool
isNumber xs = all isDigit xs || add extra code here
```

Where a valid number is defined in EBNF as:

```
number -> .digit+ | digit+ [ .digit*]
```

For example, .5, 1.5, 1, 1. are all valid numbers. +
signifies one or more occurrences, and * denotes zero or more.

Comment: I would recommend using `parsec` (or something similar) for this

Answer (score 17):

A simple approach involves using `readMaybe` for converting a string into a number,

```
import Text.Read
```

and so for checking whether it is a `Double`,

```
readMaybe "123" :: Maybe Double
Just 123.0

readMaybe "12a3" :: Maybe Double
Nothing
```

The latter returns `Nothing`, the string is not a valid number. In a similar fashion, if we assume it is an `Int`,

```
readMaybe "12.3" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple strategy:

1. Strip off all the digits at the beginning of the string.
2. The remaining string should now be either

   a) the empty string, or

   b) a decimal point followed by all digits.

Well, almost. This would also match the empty string `""` and `"."` but we can treat those as special cases.

Translated to Haskell:

```
isNumber :: String -> Bool
isNumber ""  = False
isNumber "." = False
isNumber xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`reads`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reads), then:

```
isNumber :: String -> Bool
isNumber str =
    case (reads str) :: [(Double, String)] of
      [(_, "")] -> True
      _         -> False
```

Maybe there is a better way, though.

Note that this will return `True` for numbers that are considered valid in Haskell, your particular use case is not fully covered by this. If you need custom parsing according to your specification you should use something like Parsec, as @CarstenKönig has suggested in his comment.

Comment: using this `isNumber "1.0."` (or even `1.xxx`) is `True` too - is this valid?

Comment: almost ... try `"1."` or `".5"` now ;) (all I want from you is to test your code against the specs :P - it's really not as simple as it might seem - but maybe the **OP** is fine with this)

Comment: Note that this approach will also accept negative numbers and numbers in scientific format, e.g. `"1.3e5"`.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in the EBNF. The first part should have been a .digit+ and not a :. The valiid numbers need to be able to start with a decimal point!

Comment: How can you modify the code so that the input is a Char instead of a String?