# Haskell - Validate integer input from string using readMaybe

Tags: validation, haskell

I am trying to validate integer input from a string, I just need a boolean result if the input string correctly changes types to an integer. I tried this method from another question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030649/3339668

This is the relevant code along with my imports:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Text.Read

checkValidInt :: String -> Bool
checkValidInt strInt
 | readMaybe strInt :: Maybe Int == Nothing = False
 | readMaybe strInt :: Maybe Int /= Nothing = True
```

However, I receive the following errors on loading the script:

```
Illegal operator ‘==’ in type ‘Maybe Int == Nothing’
Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types

main.hs:350:38:
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Nothing’
A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?

main.hs:351:35:
Illegal operator ‘/=’ in type ‘Maybe Int /= Nothing’
  Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types

main.hs:351:38:
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Nothing’
A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?
```

So what kind of data type is Nothing? How do I check if Nothing is the result of readMaybe properly?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `==` here at all; although `Maybe a` has an `Eq` instance, you don't *need* to use it here. Pattern matching is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Haskell interprets your

```
readMaybe strInt :: (Maybe Int == Nothing = False)
```

as:

```
readMaybe strInt :: (Maybe Int == Nothing = False)
```

It can make no sense out of this. So you can help Haskell by using some brackets:

```
(readMaybe strInt :: Maybe Int) == Nothing = False
```

You also better do not repeat the condition, but use `otherwise`, since if you repeat it, the program will - unless optimized - do the parsing twice, so:

```
checkValidInt :: String -> Bool
checkValidInt strInt
 | (readMaybe strInt :: Maybe Int) == Nothing = False
 | otherwise = True
```

Since you check for a condition such that the result is `True` if the condition is `False`, and vice versa, it is no use to use guards, we can write it as:

```
checkValidInt :: String -> Bool
checkValidInt strInt = Nothing /= (readMaybe strInt :: Maybe Int)
```

Or we can use a *pattern guard*, this can be used in case we can not perform equality checks on the type of value that is wrapped in the `Maybe`, so:

```
checkValidInt :: String -> Bool
checkValidInt strInt | Just _ <- (readMaybe strInt :: Maybe Int) = True
                     | otherwise = False
```

Or we can use the [**`isJust :: Maybe a -> Bool`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=isJust) function:

```
checkValidInt :: String -> Bool
checkValidInt strInt = isJust (readMaybe strInt :: Maybe Int)
```

Answer (score 4):

> I just need a boolean result

Probably not. You need a `Maybe Int` to pattern match on, and `readMaybe` already gives you that without any further processing.

Instead of this

```
if checkValidInt s                -- try reading an Int, but throw it away
   then foo (read s)              -- now really read an Int and use it
   else bar                       -- fall back
```

you do this

```
case readMaybe s of               -- try reading an Int
   Just i   -> foo i              -- use it
   Nothing  -> bar                -- fall back
```

Normally an explicit type annotation should not be needed, if `foo` is of the right type; but see below.

If you, for some unfathomable reason, really need `checkValidInt`, you base it on the above pattern

```
case (readMaybe s) :: Maybe Int of 
   Just _   -> True
   Nothing  -> False
```

As noted in another answer, the `maybe` function abstracts this pattern match away, but I would recommend using explicit pattern matches whenever you can as an exercise, to get the hang of it.

Comment: I completely agree. This is likely to be a case of "boolean blindness", where all the information is reduced to a boolean, since the programmer can only understand `if` but not `case`. As a net result the code is less efficient (the string is parsed twice), less readable (longer), and less safe (partial functions are used).

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite this as

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Text.Read

checkValidInt :: String -> Bool
checkValidInt strInt =
  case (readMaybe strInt :: Maybe Int) of
    Nothing -> False
    Just _  -> True
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you need here has already been abstracted behind the `maybe` function:

```
checkValidInt :: String -> Bool
checkValidInt = maybe False (const True) . (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int)
```

If `readMaybe` returns `Nothing`, then `maybe` returns `False`. Otherwise, it just applies `const True` to the resulting `Just` value, which returns `True` without caring about just what is wrapped by `Just`. Note that you are specializing the type of `readMaybe` *itself*, not the type of its return value.

Or, even simpler with an import,

```
import Data.Maybe
checkValidInt :: String -> Bool
checkValidInt = isJust . (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int)
```